# $2$ integers are selected at random from $1$ to $11$. If the sum of integers is even, what is the probability that both the numbers are odd?

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

> $2$ integers are selected at random from $1$ to $11$.
>
> If the sum of integers is even, what is the probability that both the numbers are odd?

I know that for the sum to be even, either both numbers have to be odd or both have to be even but how to find the probability?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the probability that both numbers are odd *given that* their sum is even.

So, your sample space is the set of possibilities in which the sum is even: As you remark, this can be achieved with both numbers being odd *or* both being even. But how many total possibilities does this yield? Call that number $N$.

Next, how many of the possibilities in your sample space consist of two odd numbers? Call this total $n$, so that the probability is $n/N$.

This should be enough for you to work this through a bit further. For clarity's sake, though, it would be helpful if you specified in your question whether the two integers can be the same (e.g., $3$ and $3$) or whether they must be distinct from one another.

Comment: Just to make a concrete example: Try it for 1 to 3.  To get even numbers you can do 1+1, 3+1, 1+3, 3+3 or 2+2.  So $N=5$, $n=4$ and your probability is 4/5 that both are odd.

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability for selecting two even numbers, or two odd numbers, when selecting any two from all eleven numbers without bias (nor replacement)?

Now, find the probability for selecting two odd numbers, when given that you have either selected two odd number or two even numbers, by this method.

Remember $\binom{n}{k}$ counts the ways to select $k$ from $n$ elements in a set.

Also $\mathsf P(D\mid D\cup E)=\mathsf P(D)\div\mathsf P(D\cup E)$

Answer (score 1):

**Consider this intuiutively**

$$\begin{array}{|c|cccccc|}\hline
&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11\\
\hline
1&\color{blue}2&3&\color{blue}4&5&\color{blue}6&7&\color{blue}8&9&\color{blue}{10}&11&\color{blue}{12}\\
2&3&\color{red}4&5&\color{red}6&7&\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10}&11&\color{red}{12}&13\\
3&\color{blue}4&5&\color{blue}6&7&\color{blue}8&9&\color{blue}{10}&11&\color{blue}{12}&13&\color{blue}{14}\\
4&5&\color{red}6&7&\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10}&11&\color{red}{12}&13&\color{red}{14}&15\\
5&\color{blue}6&7&\color{blue}8&9&\color{blue}{10}&11&\color{blue}{12}&13&\color{blue}{14}&15&\color{blue}{16}\\
6&7&\color{red}8&9&\color{red}{10}&11&\color{red}{12}&13&\color{red}{14}&15&\color{red}{16}&17\\
7&\color{blue}8&9&\color{blue}{10}&11&\color{blue}{12}&13&\color{blue}{14}&15&\color{blue}{16}&17&\color{blue}{18}\\
8&9&\color{red}{10}&11&\color{red}{12}&13&\color{red}{14}&15&\color{red}{16}&17&\color{red}{18}&19\\
9&\color{blue}{10}&11&\color{blue}{12}&13&\color{blue}{14}&15&\color{blue}{16}&17&\color{blue}{18}&19&\color{blue}{20}\\
10&11&\color{red}{12}&13&\color{red}{14}&15&\color{red}{16}&17&\color{red}{18}&19&\color{red}{20}&21\\
11&\color{blue}{12}&13&\color{blue}{14}&15&\color{blue}{16}&17&\color{blue}{18}&19&\color{blue}{20}&21&\color{blue}{22}\\
\hline\end{array}$$

We have coloured all combinations where the sum is even in red and all combinations where the two numbers are odd in blue

Therefore we have $\dfrac{36}{61}$ items which satisfy the constraint

Answer (score 0):

$$P(\text{two odd numbers}|\text{sum is even}) = \frac{P(\text{two odd numbers}\text{ & }\text{sum is even} )}{P(\text{sum is even})} = \frac{P(\text{two odd numbers})}{P(\text{sum is even})}$$

$P(\text{two odd numbers}) = \binom{6}{2}/\binom{11}{2}$ since there are $6$ odd numbers from $1$ to $11$.

$P(\text{sum is even}) = P(\text{two odd numbers}) + P(\text{two even numbers})$
$=\binom{6}{2}/\binom{11}{2} + \binom{5}{2}/\binom{11}{2} $ since there are $5$ even numbers from $1$ to $11$.

Therefore, 
$$P(\text{two odd numbers}|\text{sum is even}) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}+\binom{5}{2}}$$

Comment: Isn't this the solution only for the case each number is drawn without replacement? Shouldn't the last probability equal $6^2/(6^2+5^2)$?

Comment: Yes, this assumes the numbers are drawn without replacement.